# How can I the draw the curve $f(x)=x^n$?

Tags: geometry

How can I the draw the curve $f(x)=x^n$? I need to explain the uniform convergence of this curve... help me to do this....

I can do this for finitely many values of n, for example, [image]

Comment: This site is about the TeX family of typesetting systems. Other software (like Geogebra) is not on topic for this site. Perhaps this question is better suited for superuser.com?

Answer (score 2):

How about use of animation via `animate` package to show the convergent effect.

**Edit:** Another way of looking into this is to remove/mark out

```
  ymin=-1,   ymax=1, 
  xmin=-1,   xmax=1,
```

and change domain to

```
 domain=0:2,
```

yielding

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{5}
  \multiframe{30}{iIndex=0+1}{   % increase 30 to show convergence if not overflowed
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      ymin=-1,   ymax=1, 
      xmin=-1,   xmax=1,
      ]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\iIndex} {
        \addplot[
        smooth, samples=30,    % thanks to @TonioElGringo for the comment
        domain=-1:1,
        ] {x^\i};
        }
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that using `smooth` and only 10 samples will yield incorrect plots (the plotted function seems negative between 0.5 and 1). You are better off removing the `smooth` option and increasing the sample count.

Comment: @TonioElGringo -- Thanks for the hints, corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=5,ymax=400,ymin=-400,axis lines=center]
    \foreach \p in {2,3,...,6} {
     \addplot+[mark=,samples=200]  {x^\p};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]